# string vs numeric fields in a query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm getting an error 3061, too few parameters on this:

```
Dim PrbApps1 As Recordset

Set PrbApps1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [Application] WHERE [PYR_TenderRef] =" & TenderID.Value)
```

where TenderID is a textbox

I'm new to this, but I've check everything I can think of. Probably simple error but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes on the other side of your textbox value.  But if it's in an access form it should be referenced with `Me.`

```
Set PrbApps1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM [Application] WHERE [PYR_TenderRef] = '" & Me!TenderID.Value & "'")
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually needed ' as well                                  = '" & Me.TenderID.Value & "'") why I don't know.

Comment: FYI, use me! instead me.      me. references the textbox as a property of the me object. me! creates the textbox as an object, which execute a little faster when you have a lot of references. (Though intellisense doesn't work with it sadly)

Comment: I had no idea, I thought it was just preference.  Thanks @Elias

Comment: Here goes some explanations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210660(v=office.11).aspx